# Installing Nvidia driver creates GUI?

Tags: nvidia, gui, gpu-driver

Ubuntu server by default uses the open source driver nouveau. I have to have the Nvidia driver from what I have read in order for Plex to be able to use it for transcoding.
The card is a Quadro K-2000
I install the driver using,

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver-450
```

upon reboot, I have a weird GUI that I will try to describe to the best of my abilities.

It is a solid blue with the word 'Activites' in the top left, date in the top center and audio, shutdown in top right. When I click 'Activites' I get to two options, Help and Show Applications.

Is this normal?

If it is, is there a way to use Nvidia's driver without getting this odd GUI that doesn't even have a terminal anywhere I can find?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like *gnome-shell* is also installed with *nvidia-driver-450*. But the prompt does warm about that [as you can see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dsPxS.png)

Type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> to switch a terminal (TTY)

Here is an article that explains [How To Switch Between TTYs](https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-switch-tty)

Edit:
I tested installing *nvidia-driver-450* on a Ubuntu server 20.04 and gnome-shell was installed as well.